# Why openCV's implementation of Blob Detection is different from skimage?

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

For a long time, I thought that OpenCV implementation of `SimpleBlobDetector` is the approach mentioned in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_detection), in which a stack of images with different blurring parameters is created and then a search for maximal points throws location and the size of the blobs.

But I just read the implementation and it was completely different. It finds image contours in binary images of different thresholds, filters some out, and returns the rest as blobs! (kind of)

First, why is it that? I mean in most literature the blob detection means something else. Does OpenCV's code executes some faster approximation of the algorithm or is completely different and just happens to have the same name?

The second and my main question is, is there function similar to [skimage's Blob Detection](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_blob.html) in
in OpenCV?